# Formik useField

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm trying to understand the useFormik() function.

There is an example of the syntax below:

```
 const MyTextField = ({ label, ...props }) => {
   const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(props);
   return (
     <>
       <label>
         {label}
         <input {...field} {...props} />
       </label>
       {meta.touched && meta.error ? (
         <div className="error">{meta.error}</div>
       ) : null}
     </>
   );
 };
```

What I do not understand is the input syntax, why can we spread fields and props into an input tag? Does anyone know the logic behind it?

```
<input {...field} {...props} />
```

All the answers are welcome, thank you in advance!

I have looked it up in StackOverflow and  the official document, but I still do not understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the `useField` hook returns an array with three values.

1. FieldInputProps
2. FieldMetaProps
3. FieldHelperProps

An input tags needs its necessary handlers and values like, `value`, `onChange`, etc. All these are present in the `FieldInputProps` object which you are destructuring as `field` in your code.

```js
const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(props);
```

So, `field` is essentially an object with these possible values [1]

```js
{
  name: 'somename',
  onBlur: () => {}
  onChange: () => {}
  value: 'somevalue',
}
```

With the spread syntax we are essentially just passing all the object directly to the `input` tag instead of manually passing one by one like,

```html
<input value={field.value} name={field.name} onChange={field.onChange} ... />
```

v/s

Using spread operator [2]

```html
<input {...field} />
```

Similar is the case for your `props` object.

Reference:

1. https://formik.org/docs/api/useField#fieldinputpropsvalue
2. https://sentry.io/answers/react-spread-operator-three-dots/